# TabControl DrawMode

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hy , I am trying to modify a TabControl
I used `TabControlJob.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` but i didn't get any good result
so I want my `TabControl` to be in it's initial state
`TabControlJob.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.Normal`  get's the result below (it's like `DrawMode` was not reset to `Normal` state )

I would like to reset all settings for TabControl

[image]

In designer the `TabControl` looks like I want

[image]

and I have `TabControlJob.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.Normal`

Comment: Nice speech. Any questions?

Comment: :) nice , "so I want my TabControl to be in it's initial state" I didn't want to repeat myself

Comment: I understand... what does "so I want my TabControl to be in it's initial state" mean at all? From the point of view of the problems you are facing, what kind of help you are looking for?, etc. = what on the hell are you saying?!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `My Project` - `Application` tab, and turn on visual styles:

[image]

Comment: No visual styles with owner-draw, what he's complaining about.  He's looking for VisualStyleElement.Tab + VisualStyleRenderer.DrawBackground :)